# How to get json elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I got this little json file:

```
    {
    "description": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "labelEN": "description",
        "labelPT": "descrição"
    },
    "relevance": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "domain": "Indicator",
        "labelEN": "relevance",
        "labelPT": "relevância"
    },
    "title": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "labelPT": "título",
        "labelEN": "title",
        "range": "Literal"
    }
}
```

I need to build a tree looking for the "is_a" field and the name before this field. Once I got these two fields, I can insert the child one on the tree in the right place.

So, using javascript, how can I get the name and the field "is_a" of each one?

I would like to have a loop statement that gives me all the names and "is_a" fields, for example, first time it gives me "description" and "AnnotationProperty" and the second iteration it gives me "relevance" and "AnnotationProperty", etc.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not json, it's yaml file!

Comment: I'm so sorry. I put the wrong one. Editing...

Comment: Please give a sample output you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry again. Edited.

Comment: Did it, trincot. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer & snippet: it gives that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the names with their `is_a` property values like this:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (name) {
   if (data[name].is_a) console.log(name + ' is a ' + data[name].is_a);
});
```

In a snippet:

```js
var data = {
    "description": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "labelEN": "description",
        "labelPT": "descrição"
    },
    "relevance": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "domain": "Indicator",
        "labelEN": "relevance",
        "labelPT": "relevância"
    },
    "title": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "labelPT": "título",
        "labelEN": "title",
        "range": "Literal"
    }
};

// collect name & is_a
result = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (name) {
   if (data[name].is_a) result.push(name + ' is a ' + data[name].is_a);
});

// output in snippet
document.write(result.join('<br>'));
```

Comment: Thank yu so much!!! :D And just to know, is it possible to have a tree in js like it is in java or C, etc...? I'm asking this because it's my first time using js or json...

Comment: There are no native tree classes in Javascript, but you can implement it by nesting arrays and objects. There is a [lot on the subject](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+tree+implementation).

Comment: Done :D
let me ask you...do you know how to convert the yaml file into json in a js function? And save it in a js variable like you did in our example. Thanks :D

Comment: It should be possible, but maybe it is better to ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON string was valid, you could have parsed it into javascript object using `JSON.parse()` function.

And, if you want to iterate through an object, use built-in `for in` loop:

```
var json = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for (var key in json) {
  // key
  // json[key] = {is_a: 'xxx', ...}
  // json[key][is_a]
}
```